# Running Android application using Jenkins on RedHat instatnce of AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am getting this error while trying to build my project in Jenkins

```
 ...

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AndroidTest/workspace/PlacesNearYou/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AndroidTest/workspace/PlacesNearYou/gen

BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:459: /opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AndroidTest/workspace/PlacesNearYou

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried

```
android update project --p .
```

as specified in other post and forums but still no luck.

To fill you on, this was my approach on setting the Jenkins and linking it to my github project.

I create a redhat instance to setup a server and install jenkins on it.
I followede [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEQUuo5nWbo) tutorial on youtube.

After successfully setting up jenkins. I installed required plugins.
Then I create a new job and provided my github project url. And invoked ant and other stuff required.

Then later I started getting erros as the redhat instance did not have android sdk installed.

So i installed android-sdk-linux using command line and installed the platform-tools and other stuffs.

So I finally reached here and I am stuck, I am not able to solve this error.

**I also tried running `ant release` inside of my `appcompat` but it also gave error some IOException**

```
Error:Error: Cannot run program "/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-
tools/19.1.0/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

please if anyone could help me?. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be because binary libs are/were missing, which are required to perform aapt, zipalign (Android Asset Packaging Tool)

Have you already installed following things?

```
yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686
```